# Double.TryParse() input decimal separator different than system decimal separator

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, double

I have a source XML that uses a dot (".") as a decimal separator and I am parsing this on a system that uses a comma (",") as a decimal separator.

As a result, value of 0.7 gets parsed with `Double.TryParse` or `Double.Parse` as 7000000.

What are my options to parse correctly? One of them is to replace dots in source with commas with `String.Replace('.', ',')` but I don't think I like this very much.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

XML standard is explicit about the formatting of dates and numbers etc. This helps to ensure that the XML is platform independent and interoperable. Take a look at using [XmlConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.aspx) for xml data.

```
double value = XmlConvert.ToDouble(stringValue);
```

Comment: This is a good recommendation as many people are unaware of the XmlConvert class. This is particularly important when working with DateTime values.

Comment: @Chris  It gives Input string was not in correct format error. How can we keep , as a separator ?

Answer (score 21):

This does the job:

```
    string test = "0.7";
    Assert.Equal(0.7, Double.Parse(test, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: You should describe a little bit how and why this works.

Answer (score 11):

`double.TryParse`has an overload taking an IFormatProvider. Use a coresponding CultureInfo, in your case CultureInfo.InvariantCulture can be used.

Comment: An example would have been appreciated, for us lazy types.

Answer (score 11):

Easy way to specify custom decimal separator:

```
var price = "122$00";
var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo { CurrencyDecimalSeparator = "$" };
var ok = decimal.TryParse(price, NumberStyles.Currency, nfi, out result);
```