# Specify double.TryParse(..) number format?

Tags: .net, parsing, formatting, double

I get lat/lon strings from an API back in the format e.g. '37.766713' or '-122.428938' (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees) and want to parse these into a double each, however, double.TryParse(string, out doubleInstance) gives me a double of '37766713,0'. Is there any elegant way to specify the input format for the parsing? Doing string.Replace(".", ",") hurts a little bit.

Comment: Oh boy... just one minute later I came across this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844810/double-tryparse-input-decimal-separator-different-than-system-decimal-separator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a culture issue. Try using the [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c5zdc6a.aspx).

```
double d = Double.Parse("37.766713", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sigh.. should have looked a *little* longer.. this does the trick: [Double.TryParse() input decimal separator different than system decimal separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844810/double-tryparse-input-decimal-separator-different-than-system-decimal-separator)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look of the [Convert.ToDouble()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s9ak971.aspx) or [Double.parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ebt447.aspx), you can specify a IFormartProvider for the specific number format.